# Unexpected 'function' error in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Getting error is that `Unexpected 'function'` when I am using `use function view;`
My operating system is ubuntu and LAMPP server.

Please note it is working fine in windows and xampp.

Why this is error occurring?

My controller,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use function view;


class WebController extends BaseController {
}
```

and error message is,
[image]

Comment: `use function` was introduced in php 5.6. Maybe your server don't have that version.

Comment: yes. I am using 5.9. thank you for comment. what is the actual use of this code

Comment: `view` helper is available in you controllers, you don't have to import it. Just deleted that line, and `view()` will be still available in your controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can importing a function via `use function` only from PHP 5.6+.
However if your `view` function is defined in the global space, you don't need to import it at all.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php):

> For functions and constants, PHP will fall back to global functions or
>   constants if a namespaced function or constant does not exist.